# Cocos2D 2.0 - Resetting a CCSprite rotation, scale, skew, etc

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCSprite that has all its properties modified: rotation, scale, skewX, skewY, position, etc.

How do I reset that layer to the initial state (when it was created)?

I have tried to use

```
[mySprite setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

but Xcode complains this is non-existent in CCNode/CCSprite

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this?

```
mySprite.rotation = 0.0f;
mySprite.scale = 1.0f;
mySprite.skewX = 0.0f;
mySprite.skewY = 0.0f;
mySprite.position = CGPointZero;
```

Comment: I suppose this is the only way to go right? I was wondering if Cocos has something similar to view.transform, where I could use CGAffineTransform and transformIdentity to reset it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Behind the scenes, yes. But all transformations cocos2d creates are based on these properties, so changing the transform will likely be overwritten by the engine the next time one of these properties changes. But cocos2d's purpose is mainly to hide those difficult to comprehend things like OpenGL and transformations from the user.

Answer (score 2):

You could take Steffen's code and wrap it in a category so that you effectively do have a `resetTransform` method available to all nodes.

```
@interface CCNode (ResetTransform)
-(void) resetTransform;
@end

@implementation CCNode (ResetTransform)
-(void) resetTransform
{
    self.rotation = 0.0f;
    self.scale = 1.0f;
    self.skewX = 0.0f;
    self.skewY = 0.0f;
    self.position = CGPointZero;
}
@end
```